# Python/ Kivy: Reset widgets and delete data input

Tags: python, kivy, default, reset, kivy-language

I am developing a GUI with Python/ Kivy, which consists out of several Screens that contain a variety of Kivy widgets (TextInput, Spinner, DropDown, CheckBox, Label,...). I am using Buttons and the ScreenManager to switch between different screens. The problem I am facing is that after switching screens, the input data is still saved in the widgets. My aim is that after the data has been entered and submitted to a database, the input will then be deleted from the kivy widgets.

What options does kivy offer, to reset the input data for an entire screen after a specific event (Button, ScreenChange, etc.)? The only thing I came up with, was defining a function `reset_screen` for every single screen, which will delete the entire input data of a screen. Is it possible to somehow save the default status of a screen and then call it again after an event?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use `remove_widget()` to remove a `Screen`, then re-create that `Screen` and re-add it to the `ScreenManager`.

Comment: You can delete information after moving to another screen setting like `self.ids.firstlabel.text='-'`

Comment: Yes, that's the approach I used so far (`reset_screen`), but that does result in a lot of lines of code - especially if I will increase the amount of screens and number of widgets/ screen. I'm looking for a more simple and short way to do this.